# How to change return type based on inner code? (string to number conversion)

Tags: c++, string, int, return

For example, I have this code which converts from string to number:

```
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
T string_to_num( const string &Text, T defValue = T() )
{
    stringstream ss;
    for ( string::const_iterator i=Text.begin(); i!=Text.end(); ++i )
        if ( isdigit(*i) || *i=='e' || *i=='-' || *i=='+' || *i=='.' )
            ss << *i;
    T result;
    return ss >> result ? result : defValue;
}
```

Problem is it requires two arguments, the second which gives it a clue as to what type of number I am returning (an int or a float etc.).

How can I make it so that if the string contains a decimal '.' it returns a decimal datatype (eg. float), otherwise an whole datatype (eg. int)?

Unless someone has a better code they can share to do this..?

Comment: thats not possible. string is a runtime value, whereas type is determined at compile time itself. You could use `boost::any` though.

Comment: Or `boost::variant` if you have a finite set of types.  Alternatively, you could call a functor with one of the types.

Comment: You have to know the type and invoke the function as: `strint_to_num<double>("2.3");`. Remove the 2nd argument of the function as it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The question is why you need this. I think you want it, just to get rid of indicating the type before calling `string_to_num`:

```
????? number = string_to_num<double>("123.21");
^^^^^
do_something(number);
```

But, you already are indicating the type by `<double>`. A simple syntax sugar, `auto` is what you want. *(It's compile time)*

Otherwise, you need a *variant* type, and it's far from your `string_to_num` definition. It has a lot of overhead.

You're code is already OK, and the output is based on `T`. So, in real programs you have no problem.

Comment: If the OP is supplying an argument from which the compiler can deduce the template argument, there is no need to explicitly specify it with "<double>". Maybe he just wasn't aware that explicitly specifying the type is possible, so I think you answered their question.